# The maximum known number n of non-attacking queens on the board n × n

Tags: co.combinatorics

Please inform.
For which maximum number n of non-attacking queens (located on a flat board with dimensions n × n), at least one solution is known?

Yours sincerely,
Alexander

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle. (But what happens for the case of a non "flat" board...?!?)

Comment: The number of ways of placing $n$ non-attacking queens on an $n\times n$ chessboard is tabulated at http://oeis.org/A000170

Answer (score 1):

In 1874, Pauls published a proof that a solution exists for all $n$.  His solution may be summarized as follows (this table is taken from Bell and Stevens, *Discrete Math.* **309** (2009), 1–31).

1. $n=6k$ or $n=6k+4$: $A_1 = \{(2i,i)\mid 1\le i\le n/2\}$, $A_2 = \{(2i-1,n/2+i)\mid 1\le i \le n/2\}$
2. $n=6k+1$ or $n=6k+5$: $B_1 = \{(n,1)\}$, $B_2 = (2i,i+1)\mid 1\le i\le (n-1)/2\}$, $B_3 = \{(2i-1,(n+1)/2 +i)\mid 1\le i\le (n-1)/2\}$.
3. $n=6k+2$: $C_1 = \{(4,1)\}$, $C_2 = \{(n,n/2-1)\}$, $C_3 = \{(2,n/2)\}$, $C_4 = \{(n-1,n/2+1)\}$, $C_5 = \{(1,n/2+2)\}$, $C_6 = \{(n-3,n)\}$, $C_7 = \{(n-2i,i+1)\mid 1\le i\le n/2-3\}$, $C_8 = \{(n-2i-3,n/2+i+2)\mid 1\le i\le n/2-3\}$.
4. $n=6k+3$: Put solution for $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ board in bottom left corner, add queen to top right.